# How to disable bottom NavBar popup size of an item when clicked in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the image of the bottom navbar,

[image]

when I clicked the icon/button, then the logo size became bigger, like the picture down below
[image]

I mean when it clicked then the icon size is increasing, how can I disable that
I'm sorry if my question is not proper

code down below

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: selectedNavBar,
            onTap : (newindex){
              setState(() {
                selectedNavBar = newindex;
                
              });
            },
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.folder),
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                title: const Text(
                  'Home',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'futura',
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: c,
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                title: const Text(
                  'Favourite',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'futura',
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: c,
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(29.0),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'assets/nikelog.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                title: const Text(
                  'Profile',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'futura',
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: c,
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                title: const Text(
                  'Profile',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'futura',
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: c,
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet_rounded),
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                title: const Text(
                  'Account',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'futura',
                  ),
                ),
                backgroundColor: c,
              ),
            ],
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
            selectedFontSize: 1,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
            iconSize: 20,
            elevation: 0,
          ),
```

this is the bottom navigation bar's code

Comment: please share your code what you have done

Comment: done check the code now please @JahidulIslam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectedIconTheme` and `unselectedIconTheme` are two properties of BottomNavigationBar that you can use to control the size (and color and opacity) of the icons in your navigation bar. (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)